# Laptop Screen Black After Suspend

Tags: 14.04, laptop, suspend, hp, amd-processor

I'm a new user to Linux and i am running into an issue with suspend on my laptop with the following configuration

**Model** : HP Envy m6 (AMD A10-4600M APU with Radeon HD Graphics)

**Operating System** : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

**Issue** : When I close the lid of my laptop, or manually attempt to put it in suspend, it will shutdown like normal. However, when I try to resume my screen will remain dark.

I've looked around and seen several articles that have information about this, but nothing that directly relates to what I'm experiencing. I've tried a few of the other "fixes" and nothing has worked so far.

ANY help that can be provided will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a HP-Probook 5420s running with a AMD graphic card and running the open source drivers, I tried digging around a bit and tried most solutions but to no avail however after reading the comment 30 on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1283938 it worked.

This comment shows a temporary fix in which by going through settings security & privacy you can uncheck require password when waking from suspend and from blank screen. I only unchecked returning from blank screen and for the moment my systems seems to have returned to normal! I will update if anything abnormal appears. Hope this can help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a bug on launchpad. Someone commented on the bug that a temporary fix is lock your screen first then close the lid. I hope it helps.

### Original Post about temporary fix

> Kacper Hęćka (kacperh20) wrote on 2014-03-24:  #10
>   ok, so i found this "temporarly fix". When you are using laptop, first lock >your screen and then close lid to sleep mode. After you open lid system will >work ok, but notifications area will show: "Power Manager not authorized". I'm also have raden card (IBM t43).

Answer (score 1):

After several failed attempts following many suggestions, I tested 15.04 and the problem didn't occur again. So I switched to 15.04 permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Me to facing this issue with my HP pro-book 4540s i5 ATi and Intel VGA drivers. when I leave the laptop for 10 or more time it turn of the monitor and the power button keep on and off. Anyone can help us?
but After some googling I found the below solution 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1978290 
Would you please check it and replay if it works.

Comment: Rather than posting a link, would you please describe the solution you found?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on this one. I went through the fix that you liked. At first it didn't work, and then I tried the "updated" script that the author provided. Neither one seems to have worked ): Again, I thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the same laptop (HP Envy M6-1184ca) and I was able to solve the issue by downloading the latest driver at the AMD driver support page (http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) and following the installer instructions. Specifially I used the driver here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64#amd-catalyst-packages .

Comment: Hmm, this won't work for me as I am on ATI open source drivers - my card is old and upsupported by fglrx - any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I am still digging for that problem. But after following the above link the problem is partly solved but now it won't suspend anymore , but at least it helps me get back after lid is closed.

But try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> it do a refresh. It work for me sometimes.

Let's wait for answers from someone more expert in this field.

Answer (score -1):

For linux based systems it is happens because amd drivers and grub bootloader may be corrupted.
It can be resolved through the following commands:-

> sudo apt-get install grub-efi

> sudo apt-get install amd64-microcode

may differ for amd varities

(try `apt-cache search amd` // then choose your preferable microcode)

`sudo apt-get install gamemode-daemon` //for optmizing the performance(optional)

Then

> reboot