# I closed my laptop's screen, opened after 15 minutes and suddenly the display is just very dark

Tags: display

I closed down my laptop's screen (fold it ito the keyboard), opened it above after 15 minutes (unfolded it away from the keyboard) and suddenly the display is just **very dark** (not black).

Think like when your display will just go very darker. Less bright...

Besides that I can use my Ubuntu 16.04 fully regularly... And it was caused even when I changed nothing in the system. It just happened, for some reason.

For now I am searching a way to bring back the default brightness (?). You might know one?

When I go to to brightness & lock all seems fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, going to `system settings > brightness & lock` (which appeared regularly) and drag the brightness limit to 0 and then to 100, fixed it.

[image]

It was on the most right corner and I just dragged it to the most left and then brought it back to the right and the natural brightness came back.

---

I can't explain this beahvior, maybe it's a bug in the current release, maybe not and I missed something.

Comment: Have a look at posts like http://askubuntu.com/q/774540/68420. You may want to search 'Ubuntu black screen after suspend'. Also, the combination of your Ubuntu kernel version and BIOS versions may also be of interest. I ended up upgrading my BIOS and re-installing 16.10. That solved it for me.